# Android Emulator Pixel XL api 28 system Image x86 Http://10.0.2.2:8080 404 error

Tags: android

The Emulator API 25 system aremeabi-v7a : 10.0.2.2 is accessible

But when running on emulator

`API 28  x86  getting error 404 error when trying to access http:10.0.2.2:8080/`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted